# UPDATE with Cassandra CQL

Tags: php, cassandra, cql, cassandra-2.0

I'm new to Cassandra and I'm trying to update a table using this CQL query:

```
UPDATE analytics SET counter = ? WHERE hash = ?;
```

I work in PHP using the DataStax php-driver, the code for this statement is this:

```
$statement = $session->prepare("UPDATE analytics SET counter = ? WHERE hash = ?;");
$session->execute($statement, new Cassandra\ExecutionOptions(array('arguments' => array($count, $hash))));
```

The table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS analytics (domain VARCHAR, page VARCHAR, ip INET, attributes MAP <VARCHAR, VARCHAR>, hash VARCHAR, counter INT, date TIMESTAMP, PRIMARY KEY(hash, domain, date));
```

When I execute the statement I get the error "*Missing mandatory PRIMARY KEY part domain*" so I added the clause ALLOW FILTERING:

```
UPDATE analytics SET counter = ? WHERE hash = ? ALLOW FILTERING;
```

But I get another error, "*line 1:48 missing EOF at 'ALLOW'*".
What's is wrong in these queries?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error you have, I guess you created table with compound primary key (hash, domain). In order to update record in cassandra you have to provide the whole key, i.e. both values, so your query should look like:

UPDATE analytics SET counter = counter+1 WHERE hash = ? and domain = ?

For more information check this http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/a-deep-look-to-the-cql-where-clause

It says: **In UPDATE and DELETE statements all the primary key columns must be restricted...**

Comment: I've tryied it now  but it says: "_Missing mandatory PRIMARY KEY part date_" so I think that I must add also the date key, there're no ways for do that with the ALLOW FILTERING?
The counter field I can't update with in query sum because is an INT field and not a COUNTER.

Comment: No. You have to restrict on each column from your primary key. So, if you created table with primary key (hash, domain,date) you have to restrict on each of these or you can create table that doesn't have date as part of primary key if that works for you. Maybe you can add date as index. For the counter field you can update as you suggested if it's int.

Comment: I use the date key for SELECT statement in WHERE clause, changing date to index I can use anyway it on WHERE clause in SELECT or with ORDER BY?

Comment: Yes. You should be able to use it in your select query in where or order by. I suggest you try to create one test table and make all queries you are planning to do on it.

Comment: I done a simple SELECT query but I get the error "_No indexed columns present in by-columns clause with Equal operator_", in the WHERE section I wrote `domain = ? AND date > '" . (time() - 3600) . "' ORDER BY date DESC` in the table now date is no more a primary key but it's an index

Comment: Please check this answer for explanation of this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13582673/cql-select-query-on-non-key-column

Comment: I seen that I must use all primary keys and must be restricted with an equal clause or I can use the ALLOW FILTERING clause instead, but I don't understand why with this clause it give me an EOF error.

Comment: If your last comment was related to update query, then you have to provide all primary keys. You can't use allow filtering as alternative. That's why you get that error.

Comment: So in my query where "hash" is always different for each record if I want to delete or update all records for the same domain I have to select all the records with the ALLOW FILTERING then process them one by one?

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass all primary key when you want to update column . So put all primary keys in where clause .

Answer (score 0):

Are you really looking to update all counter values for a hash irrespective of date?

Anyhow, be careful with indexes. When you use an index, be sure to include the partition key so that your query hits exactly one partition. Otherwise, you have a cluster wide operation that'll likely time out in production.

If your data model doesn't support a query, but you need it for something analytical, a good option is to use Apache Spark, and use that for batch type jobs.